# CSS Parallax Effect Stretching out my Background Images

Tags: html, css, parallax, custom-scrolling

I have been struggling for the past several weeks with the parallax effect in a section on the profile page I am building.

In this section, I have three 4-column divs. The 1st div contains my text, the 2nd div contains one large background image, and the 3rd div contains two smaller background images.

I added **background-attachment: fixed;** to three images, and while it works fine with the large image in the 2nd div, the other two images get stretched beyond recognition. Here is the CSS styling that I have right now: https://codepen.io/snailssnooze123/full/BmPxgN/

```
#about-bg-selfie {
  background-image: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/aqf4nj496qeg0db/alleyPic.JPG?raw=1");
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;    
  background-size: 35%; 
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border-top: 500px solid transparent;
  border-left: 90px solid #fff;
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 250px;
}

#about-bg-pyramids {
  background-image: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/savr06trk2onj2c/pyramids.jpg?raw=1");
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 350px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#about-bg-temple {
  background-image: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/twatj0fumugvrbg/temple.jpg?raw=1");
  height: 240px;
  width: 350px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Here is what I would like the picture on the right to look like, only with the Parallax effect:https://codepen.io/snailssnooze123/full/LOBmgB/.

I have been playing with the code for days and can't get it to work. Could anyone help me figure this out? I'm afraid I must be missing something really obvious here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is the problem.
you have to remove this from "#about-bg-pyramids" and "#about-bg-temple" css :

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: Thanks, Houtan. That fixes the sizing issue, but then I lose the Parallax effect (this is what I did in the second codepen link). Is there a way I can keep the Parallax scrolling, but without stretching the image?

Comment: if you want to scroll your image Parallex your image should not be in original size, because something should be shown while scrolling. another way is that make the image larger than normal size. 'background-size' property should help you.

Comment: also you can merge that two image by photoshop into one and then load them into both divs but with different background positions.